# Importing data Elasticsearch returns illegal_argument_exception unknown setting index.analysis

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, laravel-10, laravel-scout

When importing data in ElasticSearch 7.12.0 returns error about illegal_argument_exception.

Trying to import model using Laravel 10 scout (`php artisan scout:import`).

Maybe this is a known problem? Or does anyone understand the cause of the problem.

Thanks for any help.

Returned error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "unknown setting [index.analysis] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "unknown setting [index.analysis] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings",
    "suppressed": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "unknown setting [index.index] did you mean any of [index.hidden, index.codec]?"
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Comment: I think I know the cause of the problem, but I am not familiar with larval scout, so I don't know how to fix it. The cause of the problem is that in settings "index" level is optional. So you can do "settings": {"analysis": ... } or you can do "settings": {"index": {"analysis": ... }} in both cases the result will be translated into the second form. It looks like in your case scout is wrapping it in one more index like this "settings": {"index": {"index": {"analysis": ... }}} which elasticsearch cannot accept